# Gurobi Python addConstr sum subset from list

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to create a constraint that sums the diagonals of a chessboard. The idea is that each diagonal can have only 1 piece so the variable is binary [0,1].  Is there a way to subset the variable with a list?

I have tried

```
x.sum(Diag_list)

x.sum([a,b for a,b in Diag_List])
```

And just about every other combination, I can think of.

If I do `x.sum[0,0]` I get just the point (0,0), but if you do `x.sum([0,0])` you get any point along the 0 column axis or the 0 row axis.

Answer (score 0):

The `tuplelist.sum()` function is a convenience function for slicing on a single variable. You could use to to limit the positions of a rook on a chessboard. To limit the positions of the queen, you need a more complex summation using a generator expression and the quicksum() function:

```
m.addConstr(quicksum(x[a,b] for a,b in Diag_List) <= 1)
```